# OJB / Oracle XE sql debug-display problem

Tags: java, sql, oracle-xe, ojb

I have a Java application, and use OJB as my ORM technology.  I have an Oracle XE installation locally to develop against.  The problem is when I need to debug a problem, I like looking at the SQL output.  Here is an example of SQL I can view through the "Top SQL" interface in Oracle XE:

```
 select a_bunch_of_fields
 from KREW_DOC_TYP_T A0
 WHERE ((UPPER(A0.DOC_TYP_NM) LIKE :1) AND A0.ACTV_IND = :2) AND A0.CUR_IND = :3
```

The problem is I would like to see the real value instead of ":1".  I can't seem to find how I can configure this.  I know the real values are working, because the application is responding as expected, for the most part (hence the bugs I am working on).

Thanks,
  Jay

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way is to look in the provided database views (v$sql_bind_capture and v$sqlarea).  In the SQL below, I just added a like clause to match the sql statement you have above, you will then get a row for each bind variable and it's value.  To target a very specific SQL statement you want the sql_id for your query.

```
SELECT a.sql_text, b.NAME, b.POSITION, b.datatype_string, b.value_string
  FROM v$sql_bind_capture b, v$sqlarea b
 WHERE b.sql_id = a.sql_id
  and a.sql_text like '%UPPER(A0.DOC_TYP_NM) LIKE :1%'
```

Output (without the SQL the result would look look something like this):

```
"NAME","POSITION","DATATYPE_STRING","VALUE_STRING"
":B1","2","NUMBER","1001"
```